# Why is this bufferedReader returning nulls?

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader, ioexception

I am trying to read information from a file but for each line it just returns a null

```
    String[] quotes = new String[numberOfLines];
    String myLine;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        myLine = readFile.readLine();
        System.out.println(myLine);
        quotes[i] = myLine;
    }
```

numberOfLines in the number of lines that actually has characters on them in the file

Comment: Can you edit in your full program and a sample file?

Comment: You can replace this (and the code to calculate the number of lines) with String[] quotes = Files.lines(path); however you should consider a streaming approach and not build an array of large number of lines are expected.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader.readLine` returns `null` *if and only if* you have read to the end of the file / stream:  See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--).

Therefore, you have reached the end of file.

Therefore the problem is somewhere else in your code:

- how `readFile` is instantiated / used (e.g. have you opened the right file?), or
- how you get the value for `numberOfLines`.

Unfortunately, we can't go further without seeing the code that does those things.  Or better still, an MCVE.

**UPDATE**

One possibility: the code you use to count the lines has read the file  via `readFile` and left the `BufferedReader` positioned at the end of file.